# How to upgrade assembler on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, assembly, binutils

I am trying to compile some code that uses inline assembly language. The problem is the code uses an instruction called xgetbv. It is an x86 instruction that needs a recent version of the 'as' command to use it. Mac OS X comes with version 1.38 of the 'as' command. This is too old an version to be able to recognize the xgetbv instruction. What I think the solution to my problem is is to upgrade the 'as' command to something recent. I have tried using tigerbrew to install binutils but the 'as' command is not included. I then downloaded the binutils 2.30 source code and tried building it myself. Things seem to go smoothly but when I tried to find the new 'as' command, it was not found. I don't think it was ever built. Would anyone know how to upgrade the 'as' command on Mac OS X?

This is just an example of the source code that needs to be compiled. It is very minimal and doesn't work. This code just would need to compile.

In main.c:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    asm volatile("xgetbv");
}
```

$ gcc main.c ---> should product a ./a.out file.

Currently this is the error I see: no such instruction: `xgetbv`.

Comment: What version of OSX? doing `as --version` returns `Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)` for me. I'm on version 10.13.4.

Comment: I am using Mac OS 10.6.8.

Comment: It compiles for me. So I think this is outdated because of your version of Xcode, because `as --version` also reports this: `InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin` If you want to update this, I think you need to replace `as` in `/usr/bin` But there's no guarantee this will work properly with the rest of the toolchain.

Comment: I am sure replacing "upgrading" the 'as' command would fix this problem. It is just a matter of figuring out how.

Comment: Could replace `xgetbv` with `.byte 0x0f, 0x01, 0xd0`

Comment: I replaced 'asm volatile("xgetbv")' with 'asm volatile(".byte 0x0f, 0x01, 0xd0")' and it did compile.

Comment: Here is the exact code I am having problems with: asm ("xgetbv" : "=a" (xcrl), "=d" (xcrh) : "c" (0));  Would you know the byte equivalent of this?

Comment: `xgetbv` instruction is the same as the encoding `.byte 0x0f, 0x01, 0xd0`. Simply replace all occurrences of `xgetbv` with `.byte 0x0f, 0x01, 0xd0`. So `asm (".byte 0x0f, 0x01, 0xd0" : "=a" (xcrl), "=d" (xcrh) : "c" (0));`

Comment: You might not need to use `xgetbv` yourself, if you use a built-in function to check for AVX support.  GCC's `__builtin_cpu_support("avx")` may check whether the OS has enabled it.  I forget.  But IDK what you're using `xgetbv` for.  If it's not that, then just encode it manually like MichaelPetch suggests.